# read body form request in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a request url http://my_ip:8080 and I have my custom header and body
body as `{"test":"hello"}` and I can't read body of the POST request. and my views module as,

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.db import connection
import json
import re
from hinduja.models import Register


# Register API for Hinduja
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
def hinduja_register(req):
    agent = is_valid_agent(req)
    if agent["result"] == True:
        try:
            body = get_body(req)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception as " + str(e))
           json_data = {"result":"test"}
    else:
        json_data = error_message('invalid_client')
    return response_to_client(json_data)

def is_valid_agent(req):
    regex_http_ = re.compile(r'^HTTP_.+$')
    regex_content_type = re.compile(r'^CONTENT_TYPE$')
    regex_content_length = re.compile(r'^CONTENT_LENGTH$')
    request_header = {}
    agent = {}
    for header in req.META:
        if regex_http_.match(header) or regex_content_type.match(header) or regex_content_length.match(header):
            request_header[header] = req.META[header]
    try:
        user_agent = request_header['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
        if user_agent == 'XXX':
        agent["result"] = True
        agent["user_agent"] = user_agent
    except Exception as e:
        agent["result"] = False
    return agent

# Get the request body
def get_body(req):
    body_unicode = req.body.decode('utf-8')
    body = json.loads(body_unicode)
    return body;

# Return error response
def error_message(message):
    return {"result":"error", "message": message}

# Return to success response to client
def response_to_client(json_data):
    data = json.dumps(json_data)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

while calling

`body_unicode = req.body.decode('utf-8')`

I got timeout error and got

Broken pipe from ('10.1.1.120', 47496) Can't resolve this error. Can anyone give me suggestion regard this issue

Comment: Django is not receiving the full body of the HTTP message. If this error appears consistently, it is likely a problem in the client or in your server configuration.

Comment: i set the ALLOWED_HOSTS in my settings.py

Comment: try to print `req.body` and check which parameters are coming.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare yes its print after get time out

Answer (score 0):

Should it be in this way:

```
def get_body(req):
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    body = json.loads(body_unicode)
    return body;
```